# simple theos tweak fails

Tags: ios, theos

I am new to development with Theos, so i decided to try a simple tweak from a tutorial. The tweak compiles and installs correctly, but it does not work when I test it on my iPad mini with iOS 8.4, using the iOS 8.1 SDK. This is a copy of the code from the tutorial I used:

```
%hook SBApplicationIcon
    -(void)launch
    {
    NSString *appName = [self displayName];
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"The app %@ has been launched", appName, nil];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:appName message:message delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        %orig;
    }
    %end
```

Comment: What error do you get during compiling and run

Comment: I do not get any errors at all

Comment: I am sorry if this is obvious, but why don't you try using the SDK for iOS 8.4? In the past, I've found subtle differences between iOS versions  that cause unpredictable behaviour. Although this shouldn't happen with something simple like an AlertView, perhaps the UIKit changed slightly between versions.

Comment: I could not find an iOS 8.4 sdk